VSCode seems to mandate the use of debugging mode, and cannot detect loaded project on fresh install
I'm using a fresh install of VSCode on Linux, with the C# and C# Dev Kit extensions installed as well as the .NET SDK also installed.
I've opened a fresh .NET project - console app, and immediately trying to run the "hello, world" template two strange things happen. Firstly, VSCode asks me every time to select a debugger despite me trying to run the project without debugging (through both Ctrl-F5 and Run->Run Without Debugging). Secondly, even with the correct files open as shown in the screenshot, VSCode complains that no C# project is currently loaded.
Again, this is a completely fresh project on a completely fresh install. I haven't done anything silly like renaming files or messing with any settings.

